# Outlook Mail Reply Being Sent from Wrong Account

Tags: microsoft-outlook

In my Outlook app, I have

1. My default mail account
2. And a shared mailbox added

I notice that when I reply to an email that's in the shared mail account inbox, it gets sent from my default account (the 'from' address shows the shared account name, but it's in my default account 'sent items' folder).

This happens on both MacOS and WindowsOS. Is there a way I can have the mail properly send from the shared account?

Comment: It depends. Is the "shared mailbox" able to send emails?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes I believe it should be able to. It has a sent folder and when I move to "New Outlook", sending replies are properly sent from the shared mailbox. However, there's certain things keeping me from moving to "New Outlook".

Comment: In *File > Options > Mail*, under "Send Messages", is this checked : "Always use the default account when composing new messages"?

Comment: @harrymc I just checked and nope, that option is turned off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the cause of the problem:

In Microsoft 365, shared mailboxes don't require a license and can't be added to Outlook as an independent mailbox. You can't sign in to a shared mailbox. Instead, you sign in to your own mailbox, and then you open the shared mailbox. When you send or reply to a new message from the shared mailbox, Outlook automatically sends or replies from the sender's account. Therefore, messages are stored in the Sent Items folder of the sender's mailbox.

To work around this issue, refer to this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/user-and-shared-mailboxes/sent-mail-is-not-saved

Comment: That's interesting. Thank you for finding this!

Answer (score 0):

To change the “From” address, you need to make the “From” field visible.

Open a new email in Microsoft Outlook and then click **Options > From**.

Click the drop-down box and select **Other email address**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I change the "From" address and in the sent email, the "From" address is the shared mail account. But the sent mail is in my default account "Sent" folder (seems like it's sent from my default account). Weird!